# Shiny/R error: Paths should be to files within the project directory

Tags: r, csv, shiny

My Shiny app will run locally, but when I try to deploy to shinyapps.io it will not.  I temporarily fixed the problem by removing the 'dot' in the path to the `.csv` file:

`data <- read.csv("/Users/JMJC/Desktop/bbteams-shiny/bbteams.csv")`

But when it deployed to shinyapps.io I received a different error, ERROR: cannot open the connection.

`shinyapps::deployApp('/Users/JMJC/Desktop/bbteams-shiny')`

I placed my data set in the same directory as server.r and ui.r.  And I made sure to `setwd()` to the same directory.

I'm out of ideas.  If I don't remove the dot it will not deploy, but if I do remove the dot it cannot make the connection.  If I force it to deploy, it still will not make the connection.

Comment: Simple solution: `read.csv("bbteams.csv")`

Comment: @DieterMenne Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @DieterMenne Simple indeed.  That was it.  Solved.

Comment: Small things don't count. I normally use data in a subdirectory, so `read.csv("subdir/bbteams.csv") would work. Avoid absolute paths.

Answer (score 3):

As @DieterMenne already stated in the answer section: 
Simple solution:

```
read.csv("bbteams.csv")
```

Useful link for this and other issues:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the path you give for the data file and the path for you R files is the same. So you do not need to mention the whole path, in your case 
`data <- read.csv("/Users/JMJC/Desktop/bbteams-shiny/bbteams.csv")` 
instead just use 
`read.csv("bbteams.csv")`

Answer (score -1):

Type the following into the console:

```
find_rtools()
```

This should return TRUE if your Rtools installation worked properly. If not, follow the instructions here: http://jtleek.com/modules/01_DataScientistToolbox/02_10_rtools/#6