# Why isn't my Shiny app publishing

Tags: r, shiny

I am having issues when trying to publish my Shiny app.

Here is the code for the app I published:

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Visualizing Pitcher Statistics"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Data from Baseball Prospectus"),
      helpText("by Julien Assouline"),

      sliderInput("yearinput", "YEAR", 
                  min = 1970, max = 2016, value = c(2000, 2016),
                  animate = TRUE),

      selectInput("xcol", "X Axis", 
                  choices = c("YEAR","AGE","NAME","G","GS","PITCHES","IP","IP.Start","IP.Relief","W","L","SV","BS","PA","AB","R","ER","H","X1B","X2B","X3B","HR","TB","BB","UBB","IBB","SO","HBP","SF","SH","PPF","FIP","cFIP","ERA","DRA","PWARP","TEAMS","ROOKIE","League")),

      selectInput("ycol", "y Axis", 
                  choices = c("PWARP","YEAR","NAME","AGE","G","GS","PITCHES","IP","IP.Start","IP.Relief","W","L","SV","BS","PA","AB","R","ER","H","X1B","X2B","X3B","HR","TB","BB","UBB","IBB","SO","HBP","SF","SH","PPF","FIP","cFIP","ERA","DRA","TEAMS","ROOKIE","League")),

      checkboxInput(inputId = "smoother",
                    label = "show smoother",
                    value = FALSE),

      downloadButton("downloadPNG", "Download as a PNG file")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotOutput("plot1"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("descriptionTab1"), value = "Tab1"),
        tabPanel("Line Chart", plotOutput("plot2"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("descriptionTab2"), value = "Tab2"),
        id = "theTabs"
      ))
  )
)
```

**server:**

```
server <- function(input, output){ 
  ScatterPlot <- reactive({ 
    BP_Pitcher_1967_2016 <- read.csv("/Users/julienassouline/BP Pitcher 1967 2016.csv", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
    Filtered1 <- BP_Pitcher_1967_2016 %>%
      filter(
        YEAR >= input$yearinput[1],
        YEAR <= input$yearinput[2]
      )
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = Filtered1, aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) + 
      Julien_theme() 

    if(input$smoother)
      p <- p + geom_smooth(data = Filtered1, aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol), colour = "red")
    print(p)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    print(ScatterPlot())

    output$downloadPNG <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "Graph.png",
      content = function(file){
        png(file)
        print(ScatterPlot())
        dev.off()
      })
  })

  linechart <- reactive({ 
    BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends <- read.csv("/Users/julienassouline/BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends.csv", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

    Filtered2 <- BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends %>%
      filter(
        YEAR >= input$yearinput[1],
        YEAR <= input$yearinput[2]
      )
    d <- ggplot() +
      geom_line(data = Filtered2, aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol), colour = "blue", size = 1) + 
      Julien_theme() 
    print(d)

  }
  )

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    print(linechart())

    output$downloadPNG <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "Graph.png",
      content = function(file){
        png(file)
        print(linechart())
        dev.off()
      })
  })


} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app it works just fine. But, when I try to publish it, it first tells me "line 42 Paths should be to files within the project directory"
"line 70 Paths should be to files within the project directory"

If I try to publish it any way I get this error:

"error cannot open connection"
https://julien1993.shinyapps.io/Shiny-App-3/

I have tried creating a new R document with the csv files passed to the data frames. I also have my R document saved in a file called Shiny-App-3, where I also tried to add the csv files. That doesn't work.

I am also aware, of this question. [Data object not found when deploying shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965979/data-object-not-found-when-deploying-shiny-app). That said if I place the csv files code outside the reactive function, and at the begging of my document, it still doesn't work.

If I don't include `BP_Pitcher_1967_2016 <- read.csv("/Users/julienassouline/BP Pitcher 1967 2016.csv"` line of code, or this `BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends <- read.csv("/Users/julienassouline/BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends.csv", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)` then I get the error `object 'BP_Pitcher_1967_2016' not found` and `object 'BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends' not found`.

The method described here also doesn't work, for what it's worth: 
[Shiny/R error: Paths should be to files within the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052640/shiny-r-error-paths-should-be-to-files-within-the-project-directory)

Would anybody know what the problem is? 
All help is appreciated.

Comment: In case it is useful to future readers, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829105/9096420

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is simply telling you that you cannot use absolute file paths. Try putting your two data files (`BP Pitcher 1967 2016.csv` and `BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends.csv`) into the same directory/folder as your shiny program and removing the path from the names in the code.

So line 24 should look like:

```
BP_Pitcher_1967_2016 <- read.csv("BP Pitcher 1967 2016.csv",header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```

and line 70 should look like:

```
BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends <- read.csv("BP_Pitcher_1967_2016_trends.csv", header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)
```

Test it. If you did it right, it should work. Then try publishing. It should also work fine then, unless there is another error that we haven't seen yet.

Comment: Thanks so much!! When I added it to my directory before I would do `BP_Pitcher_1967_2016 <- read.csv("/Users/julienassouline/Shiny-App-3/BP Pitcher 1967 2016.csv", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)`.