# How can I publish R shiny app on https://www.shinyapps.io/?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to publish R shiny app.But it is giving error that path should be to files within the project directory.

This is for R shiny .I have designed an app where I need to read csv files to it.App is running properly. But, when I am trying to publish it shinyappp server.It is throwing error that path to files should be within the project directory.

I am getting error that paths should to files within the project directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Shiny app publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172485/why-isnt-my-shiny-app-publishing)

Comment: You can also check out this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-