# Getting an error when trying to publish my shiny app to the server for others to view

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app runs fine in my local environment, however, when I go to publish it online I get the error "**An error has occurred. The application failed to start. Contact the author for more information.**"

When I review the error I get:
"**Line 36 Paths should be to files within the project directory**"
"**Line 38 Paths should be to files within the project directory**"

Here is the code for both of those lines:

36.
`data <- read_excel("~/data/T Version/Values for R/Pricing  081021.xlsx") %>%filter(Date_of_Indication ==  max(Date_of_Indication))`

38.
`portfolio <- read_excel("~/data/T Version/Values  for R/Portfolio for R 081021.xlsx")`

I'm a bit stumped as to why it isn't working, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The online app doesn't have access to your local directory. You need to either include the data in the code itself with something like `dput()` or include the URL to the raw data file via GitHub or something similar.

For example, I use code like this to read a csv from my GitHub repository for my online apps:

```
dat<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/RepoName/DataInput.csv")
```

But note that the repo has to be set to be publicly available (not private).

A potentially helpful link: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson7/