# Rshiny app - overwriting and publishing app

Tags: shiny, leaflet

I am having trouble updating a rshiny app on shinyapps.io

The problem seems to be with the directory. This is what I have now:

```
crime<-read.xlsx("wmsp_lat.xlsx")
```

And the error within R is "Paths should be to files within the project directory"

The app works normally within R, but when I try to publish the app, I get the following error: "An error has occurred
The application failed to start. Contact the author for more information."

I have looked at other similar quesions e.g [Getting an error when trying to publish my shiny app to the server for others to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69823842/getting-an-error-when-trying-to-publish-my-shiny-app-to-the-server-for-others-to)

I have tried putting in the full url for the location of the Excel file but still the same problem. The excel file is within the app folder, so is in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

try this `crime<-read.xlsx("./wmsp_lat.xlsx")`